# PHP IF How to include multiple conditions?

Tags: php, json

I'm working on a PHP script that reads information from a JSON API, the purpose is to collect the information from the API and put it into a CSV file. I want to exclude certain pieces of information, so far I've only had one exclusion and it worked great but now I'm trying to add a second and can't seem to get it to work correctly. Is this the correct way to join the two conditions together?

```
$structure_type = $data['sam_data']['registration']['corporateStructureName'];
if($structure_type != "U.S. Government Entity" OR "Non-Profit Organization"){
}
```

I'm trying to make this so if either one of those phrases comes up under corporateStructureName then it is excluded. I thought using OR was correct but it doesn't seem to function.

Comment: [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array) or 2 conditions `if($st != 'something' && $st != 'something else')`

Comment: Are you really sure that you cannot find the answer to this yourself given the fine documentation and endless examples on the internet?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have complete expressions either side of the OR.

```
if (!($structure_type == "U.S. Government Entity" OR
      $structure_type == "Non-Profit Organization")){
}
```

Comment: Ahh this worked, I didn't realize it had to be complete on both sides. Thank you for taking the time to answer this question, I learned something new because of this. I appreciate your time sir.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which is cleaner and more readable, is `in_array($needle, $haystack)`:

```
<?php
$structureTypes = ['U.S. Government Entity', 'Non-Profit Organization'];
if (!in_array($structureType, $structureTypes)) {
    // ...
}
```

Compared to:

```
<?php
if (!($structureType == 'U.S. Government Entity' || $structureType == 'Non-Profit Organization')) {
    // ...
}
```